# Calculate limit of function 4

Tags: calculus, limits

Why 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2-x-1}-x=+\infty,
\end{equation} Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you try and roughly graph the function and tell me what you think happens when $x \to \infty$?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici The duplicate is to $\infty$, this one is to $-\infty$. That makes the question different and considerably easier.

Comment: thank you for your answers. I have clear ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to notice that $\sqrt{t} > 0$ for all $t$. So $\sqrt{x^2-x-1} > 0$ and hence $\sqrt{x^2-x-1} -x > -x$, and the latter goes to infinity if $x$ goes to $-\infty$.